# Bringing standard container member methods to the scope of its subclass with "using" syntax does not work for operators

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, using

For some necessary reasons, I have subclassed some standard containers like `std::vector` with `private` inheritance.

```
template<typename T>
struct MyVector : private std::vector<T>
{
  typedef std::vector<T> vector;

  using vector::begin;  // ok
  using vector::end;  // ok
  using vector::size;  // ok
  using vector::operator ==;  // <---- error

  // Other customized methods
};
```

Most of the times, the `using` syntax is used to bring those methods into the scope of the subclass.
The explicit overload is done, only if I want to do something extra.

Everything is working fine except the `std::vector::operator ==` is not coming to the scope and gives compiler error:

> error: no members matching `MyVector<int>::vector` {aka
>   `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >}::operator==` in
>   `MyVector<int>::vector {aka class std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>`

I tried to simulate the situation with custom classes and it [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/vU5NV4).
With the standard container, the [compilation fails](http://ideone.com/kPMXNw).

From browsing the source of `std::vector`, I get to see `operator ==` present inside the class body.
What is the correct syntax to bring the `operator ==` into the scope of `MyVector`?

Comment: Isn't `operator==` a non-member? According to the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) it is.

Comment: @JesseGood, you are right. I was browsing the source code through eclipse and it appeared to me as of the `operator ==` was part of it. Is there a way, other than overloading `operator ==`?

Comment: I think overloading `operator==` would be the correct solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the operator overloads in the standard containers are non-members so you wouldn't be able to find them.

I'll do note however that this (from what I've read in the standard) isn't required to be the case. However it seems like most common implementations will do this. If you want to use `std::vector`'s `operator==` you can overload it like it is defined in the standard using with what you have brought in you can do it like so:

```
bool operator == (const MyVector &other) const
{
  const std::vector &this_ = *this, &other_ = other;
  return this_ == other_;
}
```